# MySQL special INSERT/SELECT statement required for updating while copying rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table a:   column type, column type_id, column_owner, column_data1, column_data2, and so on
           -----------  --------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
           'type a'      43             'owner sally' 'dfawerfd'    'yiyiyitit'
           'type b'      51             'owner sally' 'hufvgdfd'    'weysdgjed'
           'type c'      77             'owner sally' '3fdfsetr'    '4tgfgert4'



table b:   column type, column type_id, column_owner
           -----------  --------------  ------------
           'type a'      43             'owner sally'
           'type b'      51             'owner sally'
           'type c'      77             'owner sally'

           'type a'     100             'owner harry'
           'type b'     111             'owner harry'
           'type c'     150             'owner harry'
```

Help needed to develop one magic sql statement to insert new rows in table a that are copies of rows in table a where a.column_owner = 'owner sally'; and for each new record inserted, all column values should be copied but a.column_owner should be set to 'owner harry' and a.type_id should be set to b.type_id where a.type == b.type and b.column_owner == 'owner harry'.

So, the new table a would look like:

```
table a:   column type, column type_id, column_owner, column_data1, column_data2, and so on
           -----------  --------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
           'type a'      43             'owner sally' 'dfawerfd'    'yiyiyitit'
           'type b'      51             'owner sally' 'hufvgdfd'    'weysdgjed'
           'type c'      77             'owner sally' '3fdfsetr'    '4tgfgert4'
           'type a'      100            'owner harry' 'dfawerfd'    'yiyiyitit'
           'type b'      111            'owner harry' 'hufvgdfd'    'weysdgjed'
           'type c'      150            'owner harry' '3fdfsetr'    '4tgfgert4'
```

I have 13,000+ records in the table to copy/update, one sql command if possible to do the job would be greatly appreciated.

I look forward to the community's help here, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way upfront to know if this satisfies all your 13.000 records but for the example you've given, following statement would do the trick.

The gist of the query is to

- `JOIN` both tables on `column_type`
- `SELECT`the appropriate fields from each table
- `INSERT` those records in `tableA`

**SQL Statement**

```
INSERT  INTO tableA
SELECT  a.column_type
        , b.column_type_id
        , b.column_owner
        , a.column_data1
        , a.column_data2
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b ON b.column_type = a.column_type
WHERE   b.column_owner = 'owner harry'
```

Comment: thank you, i think that will do the trick as long as the WHERE clause is WHERE b.column_owner = 'owner harry' and a.column_owner = 'owner sally'.

Comment: @user1175550 - You are welcome. If this answers your question, you can accept this answer. Have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) on how to accept answers.